# OpenGL- Render to texture- a specific area of screen

Tags: android, opengl-es

I implemented FBO on my OpenGL Game. and Im rendering what is rendered to screen to a texture, the problem is that rendering to texture starts from lower left corner. look:

what is rendered to Default Frame Buffer:

[image]

what is rendered to texture attached to FBO:

[image]

But Where i want to be Rendered to Texture is:

[image]

how can i do this? here is the renderer Calass (the FBO operation is done in `onDrawFrame` function):

```
public class CurlRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

// Constant for requesting right page rect.
public static final int PAGE = 1;
// Set to true for checking quickly how perspective projection looks.
private static final boolean USE_PERSPECTIVE_PROJECTION = false;
// Background fill color.
private int mBackgroundColor;
// Curl meshes used for static and dynamic rendering.
private CurlMesh mCurlMesh;
private RectF mMargins = new RectF();
private CurlRenderer.Observer mObserver;
// Page rectangles.
private RectF mPageRect;
// View mode.
// Screen size.
private int mViewportWidth, mViewportHeight;
// Rect for render area.
private RectF mViewRect = new RectF();
private boolean first = true;
int[] fb, renderTex; 
int texW = 300; 
int texH = 256; 
IntBuffer texBuffer;
int[] buf = new int[texW * texH];
GL11ExtensionPack gl11ep ;
/**
 * Basic constructor.
 */
public CurlRenderer(CurlRenderer.Observer observer) {
    mObserver = observer;
    mCurlMesh = new CurlMesh(0);
    mPageRect = new RectF();
}

/**
 * Adds CurlMesh to this renderer.
 */
public synchronized void addCurlMesh(CurlMesh mesh) {
    mCurlMesh = mesh;
}

/**
 * Returns rect reserved for left or right page. Value page should be
 * PAGE_LEFT or PAGE_RIGHT.
 */
public RectF getPageRect(int page) {
        if (page == PAGE) {
        return mPageRect;
    }
    return null;
}
public void setup(GL10 gl){
    fb = new int[1];
    renderTex = new int[1];
    // generate
    ((GL11ExtensionPack)gl).glGenFramebuffersOES(1, fb, 0); 
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glGenTextures(1, renderTex, 0);// generate texture
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0]);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   // texBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(buf.length*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer();
   // gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL10.GL_MODULATE);
    gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, texW, texH, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, null);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
boolean RenderStart(GL10 gl){
    // Bind the framebuffer
    ((GL11ExtensionPack)gl).glBindFramebufferOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, fb[0]);

    // specify texture as color attachment
    ((GL11ExtensionPack)gl).glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL11ExtensionPack.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0], 0);


    int error = gl.glGetError();
    if (error != GL10.GL_NO_ERROR) {
        Log.d("err", "Background Load GLError: " + error+"      ");
    }
    int status = ((GL11ExtensionPack)gl).glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES);
    if (status != GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES)
    {
        Log.d("err", "Background Load GLError: " + status+"      ");;
        return true;
    }
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    return true;
}
void RenderEnd(GL10 gl){
    ((GL11ExtensionPack)gl).glBindFramebufferOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, 0);

    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0]);
    gl.glColor4f(1,1,1,1);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

@Override
public synchronized void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    if(first){
    int h = GLES20.glGetError();
    this.setup(gl);
    if(h!=0){
        Log.d("ERROR", "ERROR Happend"+h+"");
    }
    first = false;
    }
    mObserver.onDrawFrame();
    //glClearColor miad rangi ke maa entekhaab kardim ro tooye carde Graphic register mikone
    gl.glClearColor(Color.red(mBackgroundColor) / 255f,
            Color.green(mBackgroundColor) / 255f,
            Color.blue(mBackgroundColor) / 255f,
            Color.alpha(mBackgroundColor) / 255f);
    //glClear miad oon rangi ke bala register karde boodim ro dige az buffer paak mikone
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //miad matris ro be MabdaEsh barmigardoone, ke bAd baraye glRotate va glTranslate moshkeli ijaad nashe
    //chon maa asle jaabejaa kardan hamoon baraye safhe, baste be makaane avalieye
    // kaaghazemoon hast, na oon makani ke dar haale hazer gharaar dare
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    if (USE_PERSPECTIVE_PROJECTION) {
        gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -6f);
    }


    RenderStart(gl);
    mCurlMesh.onDrawFrame(gl);
    RenderEnd(gl);
    mCurlMesh.onDrawFrame(gl);

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    mViewportWidth = width;
    mViewportHeight = height;

    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    mViewRect.top = 1.0f;
    mViewRect.bottom = -1.0f;
    mViewRect.left = -ratio;
    mViewRect.right = ratio;
    updatePageRects();

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    if (USE_PERSPECTIVE_PROJECTION) {
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 20f, (float) width / height, .1f, 100f);
    } else {
        GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, mViewRect.left, mViewRect.right,
                mViewRect.bottom, mViewRect.top);
    }

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
//  mCurlMesh.setup(gl);
    gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
    //gl.glHint(GL10.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
}


/**
 * Change background/clear color.
 */
public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
    mBackgroundColor = color;
}

/**
 * Set margins or padding. Note: margins are proportional. Meaning a value
 * of .1f will produce a 10% margin.
 */
public synchronized void setMargins(float left, float top, float right,
        float bottom) {
    mMargins.left = left;
    mMargins.top = top;
    mMargins.right = right;
    mMargins.bottom = bottom;
    updatePageRects();
}
/**
 * Translates screen coordinates into view coordinates.
 * mokhtassate ye noghte (masalan pointer Position) roye safhe ro, be moAdele mokhtasaatesh
 * rooye CurlView Tabdil mikene
 */
public void translate(PointF pt) {
    pt.x = mViewRect.left + (mViewRect.width() * pt.x / mViewportWidth);
    pt.y = mViewRect.top - (-mViewRect.height() * pt.y / mViewportHeight);
}

/**
 * Recalculates page rectangles.
 */
private void updatePageRects() {
    if (mViewRect.width() == 0 || mViewRect.height() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    /**
     * @ TODO inja daghighan hamnoon kaari ke mikham, yAni size dadan be Page ro anjaam mide
     * mpageRect... khode meshe  va mViewRect view E layout
     */
        mPageRect.set(mViewRect);
        mPageRect.left += mViewRect.width() * mMargins.left;
        mPageRect.right -= mViewRect.width() * mMargins.right;
        mPageRect.top += mViewRect.height() * mMargins.top;
        mPageRect.bottom -= mViewRect.height() * mMargins.bottom;

        int bitmapW = (int) ((mPageRect.width() * mViewportWidth) / mViewRect.width());
        int bitmapH = (int) ((mPageRect.height() * mViewportHeight) / mViewRect.height());
        mObserver.onPageSizeChanged(bitmapW, bitmapH);

}

/**
 * Observer for waiting render engine/state updates.
 */
public interface Observer {
    /**
     * Called from onDrawFrame called before rendering is started. This is
     * intended to be used for animation purposes.
     */
    public void onDrawFrame();

    /**
     * Called once page size is changed. Width and height tell the page size
     * in pixels making it possible to update textures accordingly.
     */
    public void onPageSizeChanged(int width, int height);

     }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing to set the viewport for the FBO rendering. If you just wanted to draw the same part of the geometry as you draw to the default framebuffer, you would use the texture size for the viewport dimensions:

```
glViewport(0, 0, texW, texH);
```

Don't forget to set the viewport back to the appropriate size of the view/surface when you're done with FBO rendering, and start rendering to the default framebuffer again.

To draw a different (sub-)section of the geometry, as indicated in your sketch, you have a few options:

- Use a modelview transformation to translate/scale the geometry.
- Adjust the projection transformation.
- Adjust the viewport.

The results from using any of these may be slightly different, depending on what and how you render. Particularly if lighting is involved, or a perspective projection, not all options will give exactly the same result. In that case, you'll have to decide which behavior you want.

Changing one of the transformations is probably the most standard approach. But adjusting the viewport can be an elegant alternative, depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve.

For example, just roughly guessing the values based on your sketch, you could use:

```
glViewport(texW / 4, -texH / 4, texW / 2, texH);
```

This defines the viewport rectangle to approximately match the dashed orange rectangle in your sketch. You may need some more math for the values to maintain the aspect ratio, but this shows the fundamental idea.